# why don't people trade KOSPI2 options electronically

Tags: options, trading

I checked the screen market of KOSPI2 and found that there are reasonable quotes only for the first two months contracts. I understand in Korea there are some restrictions on foreign investors but I still don't understand why there is no screen market for options longer than 2 months.

Comment: I don't know Korea, but even in the US 12 years ago there was no electronic trading of long term options, not enough liquidity. You had to call marketmakers directly on the floor and they would quote you a specific option or package upon request. They did not want to leave multiple quotations up on an electronic system for any length of time (what if they all get hit simultaneously for ex.). That has been changing.

Comment: Hi noob2, thanks for the information! It's just surprising to me they don't even quote 3 months options electronically.